# Effective Way to Tell Which Threads Have Terminated

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm writing a server in C++ that consists of a master thread that accepts incoming requests, then spawning a new std::thread object to handle the task of responding to it.

This std::thread object goes into a list of threads, and I want to clean up this list periodically like this:

```
For each thread in the list:
  If the thread has finished executing:
    Call join on the thread
    Remove the thread object from the list
```

Now the challenge is how to determine if this thread (which is executing a void function) has hit the end or not. The joinable() function doesn't work because it returns true mid-execution as well as afterwards, and I only want my master thread to call join() if it's done, otherwise it's going to hang and wait for that child thread in serial rather than executing in parallel.

Comment: There's no way in standard C++; solutions are platform specific. In WIndows use `if (WaitForSingleObject(thread.native_handle(), 0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your architecture choice is "thread per request", then you should respect some core facts about the side-effects.

1. Thread execution is cheap, thread creation **is not**.
2. Excessive amount of threads living simultaneously would **waste your RAM** for nothing.

Given that, you should not bother about "if the thread is alive". Better, you should use "thread pool" idiom where you mitigate both risks mentioned above:

1. All threads in the pool are created in advance, then they live as long as the pool, just waiting for the next portion of code to execute.
2. Like a cinema theaters, thread pools has limited amount of vacant seats so you always can predict how much resources your threads are hungry about.

So, your desired flow should be then:

```
For each thread in the list:
    Wait for a new request to process
    Get next request from the incoming queue
    Process it
```